# ValueError: Shapes (426530, 2) and (1930, 2) are incompatible. Shape of one element of the dataset used for prediction is (221,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp

I am working on the DistillBert project for binary classification. I am trying to run the following code using the Spam SMS data set (You can also use the IMDB dataset, it is also giving the same issue), I am trying to find out the recall, precision, and AUC score. However, I am getting a Value error. The error is occurring at the end of the code given below i.e. after this code block.

```
m = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
m.update_state(y_test_encoded, rounded_predictions)
m.result().numpy()
```

The error can be generated using the code below and the SMS spam data split into train and test set which can be found here - [SMS spam dataset](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1De_2FL2HSWcrXQFcnTnkB0xIMTml1rmE?usp=sharing)

Here I am using the `BinaryCrossentropy` loss function and `Adam` optimizer.

Dataset: The dataset used here is the spam SMS dataset which has binary labels 0 for standard SMS and 1 for spam SMS. The same error can be reproduced using the IMDB data set for this code.

Error traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/scratch/local/46806264/ipykernel_20971/1328487267.py in <module>
      1 m = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
----> 2 m.update_state(y_test_encoded, y_pred)
      3 m.result().numpy()

/apps/tensorflow/2.4.1.cuda11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py in decorated(metric_obj, *args, **kwargs)
     88 
     89     with tf_utils.graph_context_for_symbolic_tensors(*args, **kwargs):
---> 90       update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
     91     if update_op is not None:  # update_op will be None in eager execution.
     92       metric_obj.add_update(update_op)

/apps/tensorflow/2.4.1.cuda11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py in update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    175         control_status = ag_ctx.control_status_ctx()
    176         ag_update_state = autograph.tf_convert(obj_update_state, control_status)
--> 177         return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    178     else:
    179       if isinstance(obj.update_state, def_function.Function):

/apps/tensorflow/2.4.1.cuda11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    665       try:
    666         with conversion_ctx:
--> 667           return converted_call(f, args, kwargs, options=options)
    668       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    669         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):

/apps/tensorflow/2.4.1.cuda11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in converted_call(f, args, kwargs, caller_fn_scope, options)
    348   if conversion.is_in_allowlist_cache(f, options):
    349     logging.log(2, 'Allowlisted %s: from cache', f)
--> 350     return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, False)
    351 
    352   if ag_ctx.control_status_ctx().status == ag_ctx.Status.DISABLED:

/apps/tensorflow/2.4.1.cuda11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, update_cache)
    476 
    477   if kwargs is not None:
--> 478     return f(*args, **kwargs)
    479   return f(*args)
    480 

/apps/tensorflow/2.4.1.cuda11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py in update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
   1404       Update op.
   1405     """
-> 1406     return metrics_utils.update_confusion_matrix_variables(
   1407         {
   1408             metrics_utils.ConfusionMatrix.TRUE_POSITIVES: self.true_positives,

/apps/tensorflow/2.4.1.cuda11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py in update_confusion_matrix_variables(variables_to_update, y_true, y_pred, thresholds, top_k, class_id, sample_weight, multi_label, label_weights)
    352           losses_utils.squeeze_or_expand_dimensions(
    353               y_pred, y_true, sample_weight=sample_weight))
--> 354   y_pred.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(y_true.shape)
    355 
    356   if top_k is not None:

/apps/tensorflow/2.4.1.cuda11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in assert_is_compatible_with(self, other)
   1132     """
   1133     if not self.is_compatible_with(other):
-> 1134       raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
   1135 
   1136   def most_specific_compatible_shape(self, other):

ValueError: Shapes (426530, 2) and (1930, 2) are incompatible
```

The shape of the ground truth label is (1930,2) and that of the predicted label is (426530,2). This is because the shape of the `input_ids` and `attention_mask` of one element in the `test_dataset` is (221,). 1930x221=426530. I have given the values and shapes of the `test_dataset` below. I am using `test_dataset` for prediction. I don't understand how is this happening. How is the model making predictions for all the elements in the tokenized dataset? How can I fix this to get my model's matrix?

Value of test_dataset:`test_dataset`

`<TensorSliceDataset shapes: ({input_ids: (221,), attention_mask: (221,)}, (2,)), types: ({input_ids: tf.int32, attention_mask: tf.int32}, tf.float32)>`

1st element of test_dataset: On running command-

```
for x, y in test_dataset.take(1):
    print(x)
```

output-

```
array([  101,  2272,  2000, 14163,  1010,  2057,  1005,  2128, 22210,
        2041,  2256, 27290,  3663,   102,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0], dtype=int32)>, 'attention_mask': <tf.Tensor: shape=(221,), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0], dtype=int32)>}
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import transformers
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
MODEL_NAME = 'distilbert-base-uncased'
BATCH_SIZE = 8
N_EPOCHS = 3

train = pd.read_csv("train_set.csv", error_bad_lines=False)
test = pd.read_csv("test_set.csv", error_bad_lines=False)

X_train = train.text
X_test = test.text
y_train = train.label
y_test = test.label

#One-hot encoding of labels
y_train_encoded = tf.one_hot(y_train.values, 2)
y_test_encoded = tf.one_hot(y_test.values, 2)

tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

train_encodings = tokenizer(list(X_train.values),
                        truncation=True, 
                        padding=True)
test_encodings = tokenizer(list(X_test.values),
                       truncation=True, 
                       padding=True)

train_dataset = 
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(train_encodings),list(y_train_encoded)))

test_dataset = 
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(test_encodings),list(y_test_encoded)))
test_dataset2 = test_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).take(1000).batch(16)

model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

optimizerr = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5)

losss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy((from_logits=True)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizerr,
          loss=losss,
          metrics=['accuracy'])

print("Evaluate Base model on test data")
results = model.evaluate(test_dataset2)
print("test loss, test acc:", results)

model.fit(train_dataset.shuffle(len(X_train)).batch(BATCH_SIZE),
      epochs=N_EPOCHS,
      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

predictions = model.predict(test_dataset)


y_pred = tf.round(tf.nn.sigmoid(predictions.logits))

m = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
m.update_state(y_test_encoded, rounded_predictions)
m.result().numpy()
#the above-mentioned error is occurring here.
```

How can I fix the error and get the recall, precision and AUC scores?

Comment: Where exactly? Please post the *full* error trace (and remove any code that comes *after* the error) - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: @desertnaut I have added the full error trace. Also added the dataset so that it is easy to produce the error. The error is occurring at the last link of the given code. Please check the edited post.